# Where is the file that generates the 'Items Ordered' table in sales/order/view

Tags: magento-1.7

I've found the table header file located at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items.phtml but the table content is generated elsewhere but I don't know where that is

Comment: Based on my search I would guess it is `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml`

Comment: That doesn't seem the file I need.

I've made visual changes with no affect and also I commented out "<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>" at the top of the file and the page still renders without any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml

```
<sales_order_view translate="label">
    .....
        <block type="sales/order_view" name="sales.order.view">
            <block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                    <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="4" class="a-right"</value></action>
                    <action method="setValueProperties"><value>class="last a-right"</value></action>
                    <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml" />
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
```

Comment: It's not the admin area in question. It's from My Account -> My Orders -> View Order frontend.

http://i.imgur.com/TVKeyQI.png

I would use the developer tool that you've used but since our frontend guy did a CSS job, it no longer works for me :(

Comment: check to see if that file was overwrite by your local theme  frontend/default/{theme}/template/sales/order/items.phtml

Comment: That's the file but the table body is generated with:

<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>

There is no table tags surrounding that function so I guess that functions generates the <tr><td>$data etc

How would I find what file that is in?

Comment: See /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml